# Syntax error in jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to show  the content of a json array with jquery but it returns this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

```
function getMembers(){
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/congreso/miembro/members",
    success: function(data){
        //if i use the next line works correctly
        //var json = jQuery.parseJSON( '[{"id":6,"nombre":"nombre1","apellidos":"apellido1","afiliacion":"aaa","nacionalidad":"bbb"}]' )
        //if i use the next line  i have a syntax error
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
        $( "#resMembers" ).append( "<p>"+obj.nombre)+"</p>";
        });
        },
    error:function(res){
        alert("ERROR: "+ res.statusText); }
 });
}
```

I've checked  the returned JSON string with advanced rest client and this is what I get:

```
'[{"id":6,"nombre":"nombre1","apellidos":"apellido1","afiliacion":"aaa","nacionalidad":"bbb"}]'
```

It  looks correct.

Comment: `data` is already the parsed result. [jquery.ajax: dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.`

Comment: Given that the JSON you posted does indeed look perfectly valid but also that you are getting an error, the first thing I'd suggest is writing the ACTUAL data passed to parseJSON to the console to validate that what you THINK is being passed to the JSON parser is correct.

Comment: `data` isn't even a String. It's the parsed JSON object.

Answer (score 9):

Inside `success`, `data` is *already parsed*. You don't need to do that manually with `JSON.parse`. jQuery does that much for you, this is the entire purpose of using `dataType: 'json'`.